# Why does NSLog not output aString parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I have the following code in Tweak.xm:

```
%hook NSString
- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *) aString {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"isEqualToString for : %@ with: %@", aString, self]);

    return %orig;
}
%end
```

However the syslog output shows self but not aString (should be after for :), example:

`Apr  9 20:46:32 remini CitrixReceiver-iPad[7972] <Warning>: isEqualToString for :  with: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/42123BED-A507-4CE0-97B0-20DFFD9BB78C
Apr  9 20:46:32 remini CitrixReceiver-iPad[7972] <Warning>: isEqualToString for :  with: /Applications/Cydia.app
Apr  9 20:46:32 remini CitrixReceiver-iPad[7972] <Warning>: isEqualToString for :  with: /private/var/lib/apt/
Apr  9 20:46:32 remini CitrixReceiver-iPad[7972] <Warning>: isEqualToString for :  with: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/42123BED-A507-4CE0-97B0-20DFFD9BB78C`

Why is aString not outputted?

Comment: Because the string is empty? i.e. `""`

Comment: Why isn't your NSLog just: NSLog(@"isEqualToString for : %@ with: %@"); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that the string is either `nil` or empty. Check against that at the beginning of the method. i.e.

```
if (aString == nil || [aString length] == 0) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: For some reason aString has length 0 for every call (never nil and never length >0). Just didn't expect this I guess...